# Telerik-Radgrid Issue in Model box ASP.NET webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm using Telerik Ragdrid in the model box but it is not fetching any values on `OnBatchEditCommand` in the Radgrid that I populated from jQuery.

Here's the code from which I populated the Radgrid:

```
var tableView = $find("<%= RadGrid2.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
tableView.set_dataSource(data);
tableView.dataBind();
```

The code from where I am not getting values:

```
protected void RadGrid1_BatchEditCommand(object sender, GridBatchEditingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridBatchEditingCommand command in e.Commands)
    {
        Hashtable oldValues = command.OldValues;
        Hashtable newValues = command.NewValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure you can mix client binding and server operations. If you set the data source I'm OnNeedDataSource I expect it to work

Answer (score 0):

@rdmptn in his comment pointed out the data binding. He is right, when binding data on Client-side, the Grid will not trigger server events.

Also, binding data on the client-side using your approach will not support CRUD operations and it is mentioned in the [Client side data-binding limitations](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-binding/client-side-binding/client-side-binding-specifics#client-side-data-binding-limitations) article.

To implement Client-side CRUD operations, you will have to bind data through the [ClientDataSource](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-binding/client-side/client-data-source-binding/defaultcs.aspx) control.

In case you wanted to handle the CRUD operations on Server-side, you would need to bind data using the [NeedDataSource event](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-binding/server-side-binding/programmatic-databinding-using-needdatasource-event) and then process the data within the [BatchEditCommand Event](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/server-side-programming/events/batcheditcommand). For more details, you can check out the [Batch Editing Server-side](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/edit-mode/batch-editing/server-side-api) article.